# Do all mainstream browsers use host headers when sending HTTP requests?

Tags: django, http, web, http-headers

My server is mapped to 2 domain names, and I want to return different web pages when a user is visiting the home page, based on which domain name is used.

Django has a get_host() function in request object, Django doc:

> get_host() Returns the originating host of the request using information from the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST (if USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST is enabled) and HTTP_HOST headers, in that order. If they don’t provide a value, the method uses a combination of SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT as detailed in PEP 3333.

I am not sure if every mainstream browsers respect these headers.

Can I rely on this function to tell me which domain name is the user visiting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all mainstream browsers send the `Host` header as [it is mandatory](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) for all requests sent via HTTP/1.1. Many HTTP/1.0 clients also support this header.